# Drop duplicate row with dicts

Tags: python, json, pandas

I read data from `json`, and some of them are duplicates so I want to drop them, please note that there are 2 column(`douban_info` and `omdb_info`) are still in `json/dict` format

[image: example data]

However, if I do `pd_data.drop_duplicates(['douban_info'])` (the column with json content), it would fail.

But if I do `pd_data.drop_duplicates(['detail_url'])` (a regular column), it would work.

So how can I drop these duplicates successfully??

The Exception:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a0091f87b553> in <module>()
      1 pd_data.drop_duplicates(['detail_url']) # this works
----> 2 pd_data.drop_duplicates(['douban_info']) # this failed
      3 # pd_data2.describe()

...

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Notes: where can I put the `data file`? so you can try it out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` means you have a dict in the column you are trying to use for `drop_duplicates`.

`drop_duplicates` needs to be able to compare the values in the column to each other, it does this via hashes, and you cannot turn a dict into a hash.

Because if a line is a duplicate can only be determined when two values are equal.

What you need to do is to change this dict into something hashable. Perhaps a string.

```
pd_data['douban_info_string'] = pd_data['douban_info'].astype(str)
pd_data.drop_duplicates('douban_info_string')
```

Should work.

Not very efficient or pretty, but should work.

Comment: I feel like this is a shortcoming of `pandas`. There's no reason why you'd only want to drop duplicates for hashable columns.

Comment: That's not a problem with pandas. It's a python problem. Unless you can hash a value, you cannot equate it to another value. When overshadowing the __eq__ method you also need to overshadow the __hash__ method. For values that does not, there is no way to detect duplicates.

Comment: How to convert the strings back to dict?

Comment: @Miffy you can't (in any convenient way) if you did what I wrote above. You should instead take the dicts and json serialize them. `df['dicts'].apply(json.dumps)` and to convert them back `df['strings'].apply(json.loads)` but why you would not just keep the original dicts is, I guess, a long story?

Comment: In order to drop duplicates I had to convert lists to strings and I needed those lists for further comparison and hence wanted them back as lists from string. I figured out a way. Thanks

Comment: @Miffy then copy the lists into new columns before you convert them, keep the originals. Also you may want to consider sorting order of the lists, maybe even make them into sets. if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @firelynx's answer.. You may use eval(text) to convert your strings back to dict

Comment: answers should answer the question fully without needing to read other answers first. please recitfy.

Comment: Is this a stackoverflow guideline ?